# Codeigniter PHP version without vulnerabilities

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-7, owasp

In my Codeigniter framework project, We use PHP v7.2.11 and this version 7.2.11 used in the application has known to multiple vulnerabilities. I searched for some resources on the internet for fixing this and to know the PHP version without vulnerabilities but not able to find the correct resource to use yet. Your help would be great. Many thanks.

Comment: What Codeigniter version are you using?

Comment: We use Codeigniter 3.1.6 v @Avi

Comment: Codeigniter3.1.6 is working fine with php 7.1 at my end. I don't think there should be any problem with php7.2.11.

Comment: Can you update question with  errors you're getting?

Comment: Yes even I dont face any problem in using v7.2.11 and Codeigniter v3.1.6. But We do pentesting to make application even more secured and got a report that we should avoid using PHP v7.2.11 due to vulnerabilities.